# How redirect to URL with rand key using nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, server, http-redirect

How redirect from main page url.

For example

```
site.ru
```

to

```
site.ru/?rnd=[random key]
```

using `nginx`.

My config:

```
server {
    listen 1.1.1.1:80;
    server_name dev.site.ru;
    root /home/deploy/htdocs/dev.site.ru/current/dist;
    location / {
       try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```